# Issues installing and loading package(cairo)

Tags: r, cairo, install.packages

Having a bit of trouble installing the package Cario - the code and the responses I am getting from it are below!

Already tried installing the package libxt-dev, as another post suggested, but the response was:

> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘libxt-dev’ is not available
>   (for R version 3.5.1)

```
install.packages("tidytext")

install.packages("Cario")
``Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Cario’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)`

library(tidytext) # for transforming data
library(tidyverse) # for data wrangling
library(Cairo) # for ggwordcloud package to run
library(ggwordcloud) # to render wordclouds
library(DiagrammeR) # to make qual coding
library(rgexf) #To create graph files
```

Response was:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Cairo’: .onLoad failed in
>   loadNamespace() for 'Cairo', details: call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath =
>   DLLpath, ...) error: unable to load shared object
>   '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so':
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so,
>   6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib Referenced
>   from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Cairo/libs/Cairo.so
>   Reason: image not found

Comment: Is the package named Cairo or Cario? You are trying to install Cario and then load Cairo in your post.

Comment: "Cario" as a package does not exist. `install.packages("Cairo")` should work fine.

Comment: Ahh, I had indeed spelled it wrong, thank you! However, having changed the installed.packages line and the library line, the same error message is still coming up beneath the library line - although I believe the Cairo package is now installed

Comment: Hey Ellie, which OS are you working on? Could you output your sessionInfo()?

Comment: I'm working on OS 10.14.5 , R version 3.5.1

Comment: I do have the exact same issue. But no solutions yet.